# Where to place the code when using fragments?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Android development and confused by that ActionBar and "Fragments-Stuff" that apparently came with KitKat. Just a simple question:
I used to implement my click listeners in onCreate() of my MainActivity, where do I place the magic now?

```
package com.example.alertdialig;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it in `onCreateView` in your fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
     Button aButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.aButton);
     aButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
         }
     });
     return rootView;
 }
```

By the way, fragments were introduced in Android 3.0, not KitKat ;-)

Comment: What was wrong when I posted the same solution 25 minutes prior to yours?

Comment: But it came in the ide and forces me to use it

Comment: it says : `The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})`can you help me?

Comment: @user3385402 check your `import`s at the top of your class. You might have imported an `OnClickListener` from another type. You can also change `new OnClickListener(){}` to `new View.OnClickListener(){}` to explicitly specify that the listener should come from the class `View`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button myButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myButtton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    ...
  });
  return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Kinda just threw that post together but you get the idea that now you'll put that logic inside the `onCreateView()` of your Fragments.